# Updating a JAR file gives error

Tags: java, jar, updates

I have a JAR file and I want to update a `.class` file inside that jar.

I have the `.jar` file and the `.class` file in the same directory (let's say `C:/jarupd/`)

I'm using Windows Command Prompt and I type:

```
jar uf myjar.jar dir1/dir2/dir3/.../file.class
```

It then gives me this error: `"No such file or directory"`

Comment: I've already checked other Stackoverflow answers but I can't solve my problem.

Comment: `I have the .jar file and the .class file in the same directory` - then, why are you using `dir1/dir2/...`?

Comment: if you know the package structure of your class file then open your jar via zip file extractor and then delete your existing class file from jar file and place your new class file there.

Comment: Jar file might be opened in some other program. Close them and try.